# Writing two lists one after after another to csv file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, csv

I have two lists one containing `Date` and another containing `Rf`

```
Date = ['July 12', 'July 13', 'July 14', 'July 15', 'July 16']
rf = ['12', '16', '18', '10', '4']

out = open('out.csv','ab')
writer = csv.writer(out)
writer.writerow(Date)
writer.writerow(rf)
```

But the Output in csv is not coming like

```
Jul 12  Jul 13  Jul 14  Jul 15  Jul 16  
12      16      18      10      4
```

Comment: consider using `with open..` construct to avoid bugs like you have now - not closing file

Comment: sorry I forgot last line which closes out.close()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2.x, you can use `io.open` with parameters `mode='w'` and `newline=''`. You should also use the `with` statement:

```
Date = ['July 12', 'July 13', 'July 14', 'July 15', 'July 16']
rf = ['12', '16', '18', '10', '4']

import csv, io

with io.open('out.csv', 'wb', newline='') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    writer.writerow(Date)
    writer.writerow(rf)
```

Comment: @gi.rajan, OK.. What problem do you find with the above. `with` is not exclusive to Python 3.x.

Comment: now getting error `TypeError: must be unicode, not str`. I have tried `with io.open('out.csv', mode='w', newline='', encoding='utf8') as out` but not working

Comment: @gi.rajan, See update, you'll probably need binary mode, i.e. `mode='wb'`.

Comment: yeah I got it...   Thanks for the help.